# Any EL&U appetite for a Q&A Poetry site?

Tags: discussion, community

I'm wondering if this community of experts in English language would be interested in a site devoted to an aspect of English literature?

English.SE has a [poetry](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) tag, but it is obviously about language usage within poems -- at least mostly so, scanning the list of highest-voted questions for that tag. I was needing some expert advice on an English poet, and thought there must be an SE site for this ... but it turned out there wasn't.

So, I've [launched a "proposal" for a Poetry Q&A site](http://goo.gl/aDLemi), and we'll see what comes of it. My hunch is that there are some in this community who could provide valuable input in shaping the proposal's parameters, thus this post in the Meta here.

Any suggestions, comments, feedback would be welcome here, too. (And, no, that site should **not** be about trite ditties like my question title! ;)

Comment: I'd be in favor of it. Linguists have lots of good things to say about poetry; take a look at [Haj Ross's poetics papers](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/), like ["FogCatFog"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/FogCatFog.pdf), about Sandburg's poem, or ["Languages as Poems"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Languagesaspoems.pdf), about Williams' Red Wheel Barrow.

Comment: It would be important to note that a more general [Literature.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature) site was proposed a while back, but never made it out of beta - not enough activity. I believe poetry was part of its purview as well as prose, and still it didn't garner enough active users.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - ah, thanks for that. I find it a bit surprising, actually. I would have thought there would be enough "experts" and interested to make that one fly. Maybe a matter of managing breadth and focus? In any case, healthy expectation management is valuable.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - right, just had a look at the remains of the Literature.SE site. It did seem geared towards enthusiasts and fans rather than "experts", and it was quite diffuse. Probably "Poetry" won't even get that far :) but worth a go anyway, I reckon.

Comment: I'd never go there, even though i probably would learn a lot. I mean, when it comes to poetry, i can't tell my thesis from my arsis.

Comment: I'd be there for sure.

Comment: "Experts" we have plenty of here, too. EL&U may say it's for professionals, but almost all the participants qualify as "enthusiasts and fans", as one can tell from most questions and answers. For instance, many people here think grammar is a matter of opinion and correctness rather than a natural phenomenon, and that everybody's opinion on it is equally useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a [Literature SE site](https://literature.stackexchange.com), that  as of the writing of this answer has been in public beta for 304 days.

According to the [Help Center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the scope of the site is not entirely fixed, "but questions have been successfully asked about written stories, comic books, plays, and **poetry.**"